# How to track app custom events in entire react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to add functionality that will collect custom events in redux in entire react app.

What I want to achieve is to place all event functions it in one place and only use this functions in components in my app when I want to trigger some event.

```
interface IEventsLoggerContext {
  [key: string]: (val?: any) => void
}

export const EventsLoggerContext = createContext<IEventsLoggerContext>({})

class EventsLogger extends Component<{}, any> {
  constructor (props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props)
  }

  // event methods like below
  pageLoaded = () => {
    // here will be saving the event to redux store
    console.log('page loaded')
  }

  targetClick = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    // here will be saving the event to redux store
    console.log('target click', e.target)
  }

  // ...

  render () {
    return (
      <EventsLoggerContext.Provider 
        value={{
          pageLoaded: this.pageLoaded,
          targetClick: this.targetClick
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </EventsLoggerContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default EventsLogger
```

I want to make all event log actions available in app so I wrapped all into my event provider:

```
<EventsLogger>
    ...
</EventsLogger>
```

And using in component like this:

```
const MainApp: React.FC = () => {
  const { pageLoaded } = useContext(EventsLoggerContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    pageLoaded()
  }, [pageLoaded])

  return (
    <div>Main App page</div>
  )
}
```

Is this correct way to do this or is there maybe better approach to get functionality like this?

Comment: I doubt there's any one "correct" approach. Your approach seems fine. When I think "throughout the entire component hierarchy" I think "context." :-) (But I'm still only intermediate with React.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using React `Context` is a clever way to solve this although it will require more code when adding more events compared to simply using the browser native `window.dispatchEvent()` function.

```js
// SomeComponent.tsx

export const SomeComponent : FC = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        const pageLoadEvent = new CustomEvent(
            "pageLoaded", 
            { 
                detail : {
                    at: Date.now()
                }
            }
        );

        window.dispatchEvent(pageLoadEvent);
    }, []):

    // ...
}

// SomeOtherComponent.tsx

export const SomeOtherComponent : FC = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("pageLoaded", onPageLoaded);

        return () => window.removeEventListener("pageLoaded", onPageLoaded);
    }, []);

    function onPageLoaded(e: CustomEvent) {
        // Do whatever you want here :)
    }

    // ...
}
```